# What is the difference between ある日 and 一日

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Based on what I was able to find, both means "one day" except ある日 is used when referring to a certain day. Could I use these words interchangeably? or are there situations where using one is unacceptable/improper?

Comment: I can't think of an example where ある日 and [一日]{いちにち} can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Also including furigana with {} behind the Japanese characters and including links or sources to where you found your translations is helpful for people wanting to answer you question.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed people very knowledgeable in Japanese didn`t need furigana, or the links. I guess depending on how frequently used the terms are, its possible for a native speaker to need them, knowing how crazy kanji is.

Comment: As certain kanji combinations can have different readings and usages depending on those readings, it is important to specify which reading, hence furigana necessity.

Comment: An example of this being in my answer. 一日{いちにち} is not interchangeable, while　一日{ひとひ} is (in literary Japanese). It is always good practice to include furigana if not at least for people less proficient in Japanese. Remember, this site is here to provide questions and answers for the whole community not just one persno.

Comment: What a minute, a word can have multiple pronunciations?, I mean I knew kanji had multiple readings, but I thought each word had its own pronunciation.

Comment: 一日 in particular has many more readings than that, even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of one day you found is the one in the sense of "a certain day", i.e. referring to a day without saying exactly which. An example in English is:

```
One day, he went out and never came back.
```

So please keep this in mind. This is not the 'one day' from the sequence of one day, two days, three days etc.

So now let us go through the examples as outlined in [this dictionary entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/12867/meaning/m0u/). The meaning of all the synonyms is 'a certain day' or 'one day' as explained above (I will use both these in that meaning interchangeably).

- ある日{ひ} is probably the most prominent example here. It is used like

  > 数日{すうじつ}たった**ある日**一通{いっつう}の手紙{てがみ}が届{とど}いた
  >
  > **one day**, after numerous days passed, a letter arrived
- 一日{いちにち} cannot be used interchangeably with　ある日 but by preceding it with a noun and の it can be similar in meaning

  > 春{はる}の**一日**、ひなびた山峡{さんきょう}を訪{たず}ねた
  >
  > **One day** in spring, I visited the rural ravine
- 某日{ぼうじつ} should be clear from the characters employed to quite literally mean 'some day', in that sense I guess you could interchange it with あるひ

  > 某月{ぼうげつ}**某日**、誰{だれ}それに会{あ}ったというメモが書{か}き残{のこ}されていた
  >
  > The memo said that some month **and some day**, a certain so-and-so was met
- 一日{ひとひ} is actually very rarely used and always needs furigana since one would normally read this as いちにち. But this could be exchanged with ある日.

  > **ひと日**、郊外{こうがい}に遊{あそ}ぶ
  >
  > **One day**, we played in the outskirts.

Now it is important to notice the last paragraph of that dictionary entry: ある日 is by far the most widely used and pretty much the sole one used in conversational Japanese. The latter three do appear in novels every now and then, but this is really confined to the literary world (especially the latter two).

So the answer to your question: Can one use them interchangeably

- ある日 and 一日{いちにち}: **no**. To make it work you have to construct something like 春の一日 and then it is only literary Japanese.
- ある日 and 一日{ひとひ}: **only in literary Japanese**.